# Program not recognising y values < third of total height

Tags: python, coordinates, jython, if-statement

I am writing a program to change the color of various portions of a picture. In this case the top and bottom thirds of an image.

I can change the bottom third, but for some reason the program is not recognising `if (y<h/3)`I have tried putting an actual number in place of this, and varied the way I am coding the color change.

Can someone please point out (the probably very obvious) mistake I am making.

```
def changeByThirds(pic):
  w= getWidth (pic)
  h = getHeight(pic)

  newPic = makeEmptyPicture(w,h)
  for x in range (0,w):
    for y in range (0,h):
      pxl = getPixel(pic, x, y)

      if (y<h/3):
        newPxl= getPixel (newPic, x, y)
        color = makeColor(getRed(pxl)*0.1, getGreen(pxl), getBlue(pxl))
        setColor ( newPxl, color)

      if (y>(h*2/3)):
        newPxl= getPixel (newPic, x, y)
        color = makeColor(getRed(pxl), getGreen(pxl), 0)  
        setColor ( newPxl, color)

      else:
        newPxl = getPixel (newPic, x, y)
        color = getColor(pxl)
        setColor ( newPxl, color)

  return (newPic)

def do():
  file = pickAFile()
  pic = makePicture(file)
  newPic = changeByThirds(pic)
  writePictureTo(newPic, r"D:\FOLDER\0pic3.jpg")
  explore (newPic)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `elif`, not `if`, in your second block:

```
  if (y<h/3): 
     ...

  elif (y>(h*2/3)):  #<-- change if to elif
     ...

  else:  
     ...
```

Otherwise, the final `else` gets executed even when `y < h/3`.